# Given layer's object. How do i get the view of a layer in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, layer

I just want to access the view's object from the layer associated with it.I have searched in the CALayer properties for something like "view" but failed.any one have idea about this?

Answer (score 3):

Since the view is normally the CALayer’s delegate, just use theLayer.delegate.

If for some reason that doesn’t work, I guess you could iterate all views and compare theView.layer.

Comment: Thanks david.i set other object(not view) as delegate to layer.in my scenario i can not iterate through the available views too.

Comment: “Warning: Since the view is the layer’s delegate, you should never make the view the delegate of another CALayer object. Additionally, you should never change the delegate of this layer object.”

So if you really have to change the delegate, you might want to let the new delegate know the previous one, and keep track.